# Material not applied?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been following (or trying to, at least) some basic tutorials about applying materials and textures to the default cube. There are two textures applied: first is a wood-type: colour influence. The second is a black-and-white-type: normal influence.

That's all I do before render: Select the box and add the two textures.

First one is applied as it should.

Second one is simply not applied, although it does show up correctly in the preview in the *Texture* tab in the *Properties panel*.

How can I apply the second texture as well?

Note that both textures are to be applied to the entire box, not to selected faces of it.

(Using Blender 2.77a, rendering with Blender Internal).

**UPDATE**

[image]
Left: preview, center: 3d view, right: render

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com please? Thanks!

Comment: Consider the process described here. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: @Lukaash done (see edit above)

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of linked one, because this one has nothing to do with assigning different materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bump map texture influence is not visible because you have wrong texture coordinates.

Either unwrap your mesh or change the type of used texture coordinates.

- **Change Coordinates** - Since it is a procedural texture you don't necessarily have to unwrap your mesh for the texture to be visible. Just go into the *Properties Window > Texture Tab* select your *Stucci* texture named "Texture" and in the *Mapping panel > Coordinates* change from *UV* to either *Generated* or *Object*.
- **Unwrap Mesh** - You may optionally prefer unwrapping your mesh. Just <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* select all faces with <kbd>A</kbd> and Unwrap with <kbd>U</kbd>. Select your preferred method. For quick results just use *Cube Projection*.